# How to permanently resolve Symfony2 twig_upper_filter error?

Tags: symfony, twig

Situation:

1. Production mode
2. Change a file
3. One of the pages on the site returns the following 500 internal error.
4. Run composer update, and the error goes away.
5. Change a file and the problem returns.

The code calling the twig_upper_filter is buried deep inside the now embedded in symfony bootstrap templates.

What does composer update do that might fix this? It is repeatable (on one server only).

```
UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function 
"twig_upper_filter" from the global namespace." at
```

Symfony 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting the web server build the cache resolved the problem. The command line environment must not be exactly the same as the web server php. On this server it is difficult to actually run command line scripts as the web server user.

Therefore, clearing the cache on the command line with no warmup is the work around:

```
php ./app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

Because at the end of composer update it does a cache clear, everytime you change something somewhere you need to clear the cache for the change to be visible in the production enviroment.

This is automatic on the development enviroment.

You need to run this from console:

```
cd /your/symfony/app
php ./app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: No sadly git script does exactly this.  I think I have it though. Using --no-warmup instead of --env=prod seems to be OK.

Comment: What file are you exactly changing?

Comment: Also you **NEED** to use the `--env=prod` to clear the production cache but you can use both `--no-warmup --env=prod` not that it makes a difference, the "warmup" then is made when you load a page

Comment: composer update seems to just call --no-warmup. I have now got --env=prod and --no-debug and --no-warmup and it seems to work. Maybe there is something different between my web server user and user running the command.

Comment: Yes, they're different users. When you call `php ./app/console` from the cli, the script runs with your user. When you access the `app.php` from your browser, symfony runs with your webserver user (apache, nobody, www-data, etc) check the link to see how to fix permissions for the cache: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup